# split a string into string and integer bash

Tags: bash, parsing

I need to program a football league table with football round results in a text file of this format

```
abc 4 def 5 ghi 9 hef 10
```

where format is

```
[home team][home team points][guest team][guest team points]
```

And the program will accept five teams and have multiple text files to read. What I don't know is how to get the points of each correspond team. I have seen some solutions on parsing string with one whitespace and delimiter in this site. However, I need to read like this `abc 4`  `def 5` and so on. Is there any solutions?

The following is the code at this moment. I just figuring out how to read correspond scores of a team.  Thanks for your kindly help.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "No argument"
else
   echo "The number of arguments : $#" 
   echo "The full list : $@"
   myArray=("$@")
   echo "${myArray[0]}"
   arraylength=${#myArray[@]}
   declare -p myArray
   #loop for places entered
   for ((i=0;i<${arraylength};i++)); 
   do 
    #iterate on the files stored to find target
    for matchfile in match*.txt;
        do  
        declare file_content=$( cat "${matchfile}" )
        #check whether a file has target lanaguage
        if [[ " $file_content " =~ ${myArray[i]} ]] # please note the space before and after the file content
            then  
              #awk -v a="$file_content" -v b="${myArray[i]}" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}'
              #echo "${myArray[i]}" 
              #let j=j+1
         echo "${myArray[i]} found in ${matchfile}: with a score ..."

                    fi
        done
    done
    fi
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a regex match going with:

```
if [[ " $file_content " =~ ${myArray[i]} ]]; then
```

You can adjust it like so:

```
re="(^| )${myArray[i]} ([0-9]*)( |$)"
if [[ $file_content =~ $re ]]; then
```

The `(^| )` and `( |$)` parts make sure it works if there's space or the start or end of the file after the team name.  The `([0-9]*)` part is to capture the score into a "capture group".

Running that regex match will populate the array `BASH_REMATCH` with all the matches from the comparison, so `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` will have the score.